# How to build a RFC 3161 time stamp using Bouncy Castle

Tags: pdf, timestamp, bouncycastle, pki, rfc3161

we need to implement our own PDF timestamping mechanism based on X509 certificate (including private key of course) and RFC 3161. I've googled and asked [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333322/offline-pdf-timestamping-using-itext) and proper solution would be to re-implement TSAClient class to do timestamping locally for us (without online TSA). However I didn't find any implementation of RFC 3161 except SecureBlackbox components. It should be possible with Bouncy Castle libraries but I don't know how.

Can you please point me to right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to generate a RFC3161 timestamp token with Bouncycastle libraries.

First create a TimestampRequest. For your case it is only a wrapper for the digest algorithm and the digest value.

```
byte[] document = /* ... */
byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA256").digest(document);
TimeStampRequestGenerator tsReqGen = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
TimeStampRequest tsReq = tsReqGen.generate(CMSAlgorithm.SHA256, digest);
```

Then generate the token

```
DigestCalculator dgCalc = new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build();
ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder().build(getPrivateKey());
SignerInfoGenerator siGen = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder()).build(signer, getCertificate());
ASN1ObjectIdentifier policy = new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("1.2.3.4.5.6"); // Replace by your timestamping policy OID
TimeStampTokenGenerator tstGen = new TimeStampTokenGenerator(siGen, dgCalc, policy);
/* Set the parameters e.g. set the accuracy or include the signing certificate */
TimeStampToken tst = tstGen.generate(tsReq, generateSerialNumber(), new Date());
byte[] encoding = tst.getEncoded();
```

Comment: This is not an adequate code. Many missing and incorrect elements. do provide a working example or at least inform where placeholders are (e.g. variables that are not bound)